# Cannot access a variable from an event listener in one JavaScript file, in a different JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

The user can input data values, and then the mean of their values is calculated when they click dataButtonB. I then want to be able to access the value of the mean in a separate javascript file, however I currently cannot get this to work.

sampleB.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/t.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="testbody">
    <div class="bsample">
        <div class="headings">
            <h2 class="bheading">Sample B</h2>
            <h3 class="bsubheading">Sample Size</h3>
        </div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="B" autocomplete="off" class="binput input">
        <div id="addItemsB" class="addItems"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="bsubmit submitButton">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <script src="sampleBScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

sampleBScript.js

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    const buttonB = document.querySelector('.bsubmit')
    const subheadingB = document.querySelector('.bsubheading')
    const inputB = document.querySelector('.binput')
    const addItemsB = document.getElementById('addItemsB')
    let b = ''
    let totalB = 0;
    let meanB = 0;
    const resultsURL = 'http://localhost:3000/results.html'
    
    buttonB.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let b = inputB.value;
        if(b=='') {
            subheadingB.textContent = 'Values Required'
        } else if (b < 3 || b > 15) {
            subheadingB.textContent = 'Invalid Sample Size'
        } else {
            subheadingB.textContent = 'Data Set';
            inputB.remove();
            buttonB.remove();
            for(i=0; i<b; i++) {
                // Creates number input boxes for sample b
                let input = document.createElement("input")
                input.type = "number"
                input.name = "bValue" + i
                input.classList.add("bValue", "dataValueInput", "dataValueInputB" + i)
                addItemsB.appendChild(input)
                addItemsB.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
            }
            // Creates button to submit data values for sample b
            let dataButtonB = document.createElement("button")
            dataButtonB.classList.add("dataButton", "dataButtonB")
            dataButtonB.textContent = "Submit B"
            addItemsB.appendChild(dataButtonB)
    
            // When dataButtonB clicked, meanB is calculated
            dataButtonB.addEventListener('click', () => {
                let sampleSizeB = i;
                for(i=0; i<b; i++) {
                    let value = document.querySelector('.dataValueInputB' + i ).value 
                    totalB += parseInt(value)
                }
                meanB = totalB/sampleSizeB;
                console.log(meanB)
                window.location.assign(resultsURL)
            })
        }
    })
})
```

results.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/t.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="results"></h3>
    <script src="sampleAScript.js"></script>
    <script src="sampleBScript.js"></script>
    <script src="resultsScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

resultsScript.js

```
console.log(meanB)
```

I'm struggling to access the mean of the data set in resultsScript.js. I'm getting the following errors:

```
sampleBScript.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at sampleBScript.js:16:13
```

and:

```
resultsScript.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: meanB is not defined
    at resultsScript.js:1:13
```

I thought to resolve these errors by using DOMLoadedContent, but I get the same errors whether or not I use that. I've also tried:

```
// Variables

const buttonB = document.querySelector('.bsubmit')
const subheadingB = document.querySelector('.bsubheading')
const inputB = document.querySelector('.binput')
const addItemsB = document.getElementById('addItemsB')
let a = ''
let totalB = 0;
let meanB = 0;
const resultsURL = 'http://localhost:3000/results.html'

// Main

if (buttonB) {
    buttonb.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let b = inputB.value;
        if(b=='') {
            subheadingB.textContent = 'Values Required'
        } else if (b < 3 || b > 15) {
            subheadingB.textContent = 'Invalid Sample Size'
        } else {
            subheadingB.textContent = 'Data Set';
            inputB.remove();
            buttonB.remove();
            for(i=0; i<b; i++) {
                // Creates number input boxes for sample b
                let input = document.createElement("input")
                input.type = "number"
                input.name = "bValue" + i
                input.classList.add("bValue", "dataValueInput", "dataValueInputB" + i)
                addItemsB.appendChild(input)
                addItemsB.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
            }
            // Creates button to submit data values for sample a
            let dataButtonB = document.createElement("button")
            dataButtonB.classList.add("dataButton", "dataButtonB")
            dataButtonB.textContent = "Submit B"
            dataButtonB.type = "submit"
            addItemsB.appendChild(dataButtonB)
    
            // Adds functionality to dataButtonB
            dataButtonB.addEventListener('click', () => {
                let sampleSizeB = i;
                for(i=0; i<b; i++) {
                    let value = document.querySelector('.dataValueInputB' + i ).value 
                    totalB += parseInt(value)
                }
                meanB = totalB/sampleSizeB;
                console.log(meanB)
                window.location.assign(resultsURL)
            })
        }
        
    })
}
```

But with this method it just skips over the event listener entirely, and you get no error, but you also don't get the mean outputted to the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed `meanB` to `meanA` in the second code snippet. That makes harder to understand the case. Be more careful please.

You are trying a wrong worklow:

- you navigate to another URL (`location.assign`)
- open another URL
- trying to access a local function variable on the previous page

Looks not a working workflow at all.

You should store your `meanB` between the page navigation:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('meanB', meanB);
```

then read it when you need it on the next page:

```
console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('meanB'));
```

Comment: Agreed, but this doesn't guarantee `meanB` will have the desired value when accessed.

Comment: I'm not sure tbh. This is likely enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/989920 comes to mind

Comment: @evolutionxbox as always i hurry not read a question to the end :)))

Comment: Just tried this, but I'm still getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at sampleBScript.js:16:13
I don't think results.js can even read what's in the event listener for buttonB (unless I am mistaken)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') - that's not related, you don't get your element right

Comment: It works now - I was mistaken - thanks!

Comment: @anousheh21 you are welcome. also i upvoted your question so you know have 15 rep points and could upvote my answer too (the arrow up), thanks!